# array[oListItem.id] has values but array[6], array[7] etc. are undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, sharepoint

I retrieve values from a SharePoint list and put them in an array `itemprices`.

Using `console.log("Price of list item at is:" + itemprices[oListItem.id]);` will print out the values of the array, but using `console.log("itemprices 5: " + itemprices[5]);` tells me that they are undefined:

[image: undefined]

This is the code I used:

```
var itemprices = [];

// Gets values from Catalogue list; but they can't be used in the Position list because of different formats
function retrieveListItems() {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    catalogueList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Catalog');

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery(); // initiate the query object
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><In><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/><Values><Value Type=\'Number\'>5</Value><Value Type=\'Number\'>6</Value><Value Type=\'Number\'>7</Value></Values></In></Where></Query></View>');
    itemColl = catalogueList.getItems(camlQuery);

    // returns the item collection based on the query
    context.load(itemColl);
    context.executeQueryAsync(retrieveListItemsSuccess, retrieveListItemsFail);
}

function retrieveListItemsSuccess() {
    var listItemEnumerator = itemColl.getEnumerator();
    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        itemprices[oListItem.id] = oListItem.get_item('Preis');
        console.log("itemprices 5: " + itemprices[5]);
        console.log("itemprices 6: " + itemprices[6]);
        console.log("itemprices 7: " + itemprices[7]);
        console.log("Price of list item at is:" + itemprices[oListItem.id]);
    }
}
// This function is executed if the above call fails
function retrieveListItemsFail(sender, args) {
    alert('Failed to get list items. Error:' + args.get_message());
}
```

I don't know if this is a JavaScript issue or a SharePoint issue. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you get if you run this?: `console.log(oListItem.id, ' is type ', typeof oListItem.id)`

Comment: `undefined " is type " "undefined"`

Comment: Well, there you go: the id is actually undefined, so you're setting the value on the array with the key `undefined`, not numeric keys :)

Comment: @IceMetalPunk Oh I see. So I should define a `var i = 0` and assign the list items to the array at the position `i` and increment it with `i++;` instead?

Comment: That would work, but it would be different behavior from what you currently seem to be trying to do. You should find out why the `id` property of your list items is undefined in the first place and fix that :)

Comment: Alright. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, please use the right ClientContext object, in the code snippet above, it should be clientContext rather than context and if you want to populate field values into an array, try to use array.push, here is the modified code snippet for your reference:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(retrieveListItems, 'sp.js');
var itemprices = [];
// Gets values from Catalogue list; but they can't be used in the Position list because of different formats
function retrieveListItems() {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    catalogueList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Companies');

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery(); // initiate the query object
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><In><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/><Values><Value Type=\'Number\'>5</Value><Value Type=\'Number\'>6</Value><Value Type=\'Number\'>7</Value></Values></In></Where></Query></View>');
    itemColl = catalogueList.getItems(camlQuery);

    // returns the item collection based on the query
    clientContext.load(itemColl);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(retrieveListItemsSuccess, retrieveListItemsFail);
}

function retrieveListItemsSuccess() {
    var listItemEnumerator = itemColl.getEnumerator();
    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        itemprices.push(oListItem.get_item('Title'));
      }
      console.log(itemprices);
 }
// This function is executed if the above call fails
function retrieveListItemsFail(sender, args) {
    alert('Failed to get list items. Error:' + args.get_message());
}
</script>
```

This is my list data:

[image]

This is the array from Console:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can just use this function:

itemprices.map(itemPrice => console.log(itemPrice))

Comment: Why would you map items to the (always undefined) result of `console.log`?